# Flot Chart - different color on single line chart based on data points

Tags: javascript, charts, colors, flot, linechart

Basically, I am pulling data using AJAX from MySQL to plot line chart.
Now I want different colors for points on my line chart based on data. As in if data falls within the range it will be a different color and outside range it will be a different color. Someone please suggest or guide. Code used below:

I have tried using Flot threshold plugin which is available below but it's not working.

```
var offset = 0;
//plot(html);
var options = {
    colors: ["#3fcf7f"],
    threshold: {
        below: 200,
        colors: ["#ff7070"]
    },
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: {
                colors: [{
                    opacity: 0.0
                }, {
                    opacity: 0.2
                }]
            },
        },
        points: {
            radius: 5,
            show: true
        },
        shadowSize: 2
    },
    grid: {
        color: "#fff",
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#f0f0f0",
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    //colors: ["#ff7070"],
    xaxis: {
        mode: 'time',
        timeformat: '%d/%m/%y',
        //rotateTicks: 90
    },
    yaxis: {
        ticks: 5,
        tickDecimals: 0,
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%y.1 on %x.4",
        defaultTheme: false,
        shifts: {
            x: 0,
            y: 20
        }
    }
};
console.log(html.data);
console.log(html.data[0][0]);
data.push(html);
// A null signifies separate line segments

$.plot("#flot-color", data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `colors` property, and the `color` and `threshold` properties belong inside the `series` property. Change your options to this:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        color: "#3fcf7f",
        threshold: {
            below: 200,
            color: "#ff7070"
        },
        lines: {
        ...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls6pmLhh/) that shows a working chart.

Comment: Have tried color as well.. it doesn't work in either cases

Comment: @prashantsudeep See the edited answer, there was another error.